# $\int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} |f(t)| dt < \infty \implies \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t) dt$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

[image]

I've found counter example for $(A),(D)$ and have shown except a bounded interval $F$ is uniformly continuous everywhere else. And so $(B)$ would imply $(C)$ is correct. But I can't show $(B)$ is correct. Please help someone.

Comment: If $C$ was correct, so would $B$ be. So you only need to decide about $C$.

Comment: I even couldn't show $C$. I can only show $B \implies C$ :(

Comment: You know that $C \implies B$, beause if a function $g$ is uniformly continuous, then $g$ is continuous. Why $B \implies C$?

Comment: Because you can show except a bounded interval $F$ is uniformly continuous, so continuity implies $F$ uniformly cont on that bounded interval and hence everywhere

Comment: Actually,  $\int |f| < \infty$ does not imply $F(x)$ is well-defined.

Comment: @zhw why ? Can you give a counter example ?

Comment: $|f|$ integrable on $[a,b]$ does not imply $f$ integrable on $[a,b].$ It's easy to fix: Just assume  f  integrable on each [a,b]

Answer (score -2):

HINT: For (B) consider $G_a(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ and remind fundamental theorem of calculus.
$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^a f(t)\,dt + G_a(x)$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @dragoboy $f$ is integrable on every bounded interval, say $[a,b]$. Hence $G_a(x)$ is continuous on every finite interval, and $F(x)=G_a(x)+const$ for $x>a$.

Comment: Sorry, but can you please prove your first line ?

Comment: @dragoboy If improper integral of $|f|$ exists, so does that of $f$. But integrability in Riemann sense is in the definition of improper integral, hence pathology as $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ for rationals and $f(x)=-e^{-x^2}$ for irrationals is impossible.